# Why Genymotion doesn't work even if VirtualBox installed?

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

Firstly, I have installed VirtualBox throught the terminal. After that installed Genymotion. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04. But Genymotion tells that I need to install VirtualBox. What can be the reason for that?

[image]

Comment: It seems the same issue with a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/40935696/1810128

Comment: What errors do you get when running `virtualbox` in a terminal?

Comment: @bistoco It simply advices me to reinstall VirtualBox. It did not work for me

Comment: What's the output for `whereis virtualbox`

Comment: @Takkat I did not try to run virtualbox via terminal. It perfectly works, I checked it by finding it through the search and clicking on icon)

Comment: @bistoco virtualbox: /usr/bin/virtualbox /usr/lib/virtualbox /usr/share/virtualbox /usr/share/man/man1/virtualbox.1.gz

Comment: The output of `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv status`

Comment: @bistoco what to write before `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv status` in order to execure command?

Comment: that's the command to see if virtualbox modules are loaded in kernel. My ouput is `VirtualBox kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) are loaded.`

Comment: @bistoco I put `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv status` on terminal,but it tells that there is no such directory or catalog. Check your command syntax pls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64906/discussion-between-bistoco-and-andy11).

Answer (score 1):

I get this when I've used up all 128 of my host-only NAT adapters,

I've searched the web and there doesn't seem to be way to a) remove them all in a batch or b) make Genymotion use the same one instead of creating a new one every time it starts. (Although one page I read made it sound like that is supposed to be the case!)

The fix for me:

1. Start VirtualBox
2. Go to File -> Preferences -> Network and open the "Host-only Networks" tab
3. One by one remove the vboxnet(0 to 127)'s!

Although you could just remove one and then start Genymotion - but you'd have to do it again next time! :)

Now if anyone knows how to stop Genymotion creating them ...

Comment: This workaround helped me a lot. Are you sting removing all those adapters? Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded/installed GenyMotion first then installed VirtualBox. Try rebooting your system, then relaunching GenyMotion. After doing this I was able to get the emulator up and working.